# How to exclude a required VAT number field only for guest checkout in Magento

Tags: magento, field, checkout

Is it possible to exclude the VAT number field from the guest checkout, while keeping the VAT number as a required field for registered customers? 
We are using the European VAT validation module of Magento 1.7.

Comment: Can you [edit] the Question and add what did you find while researching for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I took a quick look around the Magento XML files for VAT. I don't think you can specify it as depending on logged in vs not logged in because it seems to be a field set in `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/checkout/etc/config.xml`.

**Actually line 74** (Magento 1.7.0.0) of `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml` looks interesting:

```
<?php if ($this->helper('customer/address')->isVatAttributeVisible()) : ?>
```

I suggest a modification to

```
<?php if ($this->helper('customer/address')->isVatAttributeVisible() && $this->isCustomerLoggedIn()) : ?>
```

And all you need to do is to place your modified checkout/onepage/billing.phtml in your template path. (line 152, `<?php if ($_taxvat->isEnabled()): ?>`, might be relevant too.)

If you have very different requirements for logged in vs logged out users then you might want to make completely new templates, one for each state and use your local.xml to control what is displayed:

```
<layout>
  <!-- ... -->
    <customer_logged_out>
        <reference name="checkout.onepage.billing">
          <action method="setTemplate"><template>checkout/onepage/billingloggedout.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </customer_logged_out>

    <customer_logged_in>
        <reference name="checkout.onepage.billing">
          <action method="setTemplate"><template>checkout/onepage/billingloggedin.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </customer_logged_in>
  <!-- ... -->
</layout>
```

But making new blocks for the checkout might not be trivial (and you might need to use reference `name="billing"` instead of reference `name="checkout.onepage.billing"`).

Comment: Unfortunately that didn´t work. As the registered account will be created after the completed checkout, I think we have to use something like: if($this->getQuote()->getCheckoutMethod() == "register" || Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() ) . However I´m not sure how to add it to the onepage checkout. 
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() )

Comment: Oh, I see. Then I think you will need to modify or add to the javascript of the one step checkout form to conditionally show or hide the VAT box depending on the value of the radio buttons `id="login:guest"` and `id="login:register"`. It will need to be done in Javascript because Magento can't know which radio button was pressed - that is all in the browser. I don't think that will be too difficult. If you want more details let me know here or edit your question, or ask a new one.

Comment: By adding the code AND ($this->getQuote()->getCheckoutMethod() == "register" || Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) it works. Only the cache of the one checkout page breacks it, if a customer goes back and changes his choice. So, if it is possible by Javascript, than this could be a better solution. Do you have more details in which javascript I have to put the code and can you give me some hints for the code? Thank you very much!